# comparing parameter from stdout to string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to compare a parameter from stdout to a known string I have,
So if there  is a match between the two strings it will give me **exit code 0**,
And in the case of a mismatch, it will end with **exit code 1**.

I tried to insert stdout into parameter from a function output but I get an error.

***This is the code I use:***

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output

def pwd():
    pwdcmd = subprocess.call("pwd")

out = check_output([pwd()])
print "this is where you are --> " + out
```

From what I've read and tried using the same command on a command and not a function it works:

```
out = check_output(["pwd"])
print "this is where you are --> " + out
```

How do I put the stdout inside "out" parameter from a function?

***This is the error I get:***

**

```
/opt/sign
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sign/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    out = check_output([pwd()])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

**

Comment: Can you give an example what this means *I'm trying to compare a parameter from stdout to a known string I have,*. I don't see any comparison in your code.

Comment: @MikeMüller my problem is not with comparing but with getting the parameter from my function stdout to a parameter.

Comment: The answer I just posted should be what you need. Or give you enough to do whatever else you're doing from the example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are up to. But this would work:

```
import subprocess

def pwd():
    return subprocess.check_output(["pwd"])

out = pwd()
print "this is where you are --> " + out
```

Simpler:

```
import os 

print "this is where you are --> " + os.getcwd()
```

The second solution is platform-independent and there is no question how decode the bytestring the subprocess call gives you in Python 3.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear, trying to take stdout from simple cmd like 'pwd' works. My issue is when taking the stdout from a function like: out = check_output([function()])

Comment: Just to clarify, is your goal to get the current directory from which your script was run? Or do you intend to use this with different commands, and pwd is just the one you chose for the example. I ask because if all you want is the equivalent of pwd, but within python, there are much, much better ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses `subprocess.Popen` instead of subprocess.call, and reads your commands from a `list of lists` instead of a function. This should give you what you need:

```
import subprocess

# This list contains a list for each command, with list[0]
# being your desired output message, and list[1] being a list
# containing a command and its arguments.
command_list = [
                    ["This is where you are -> ", ["pwd"]],
                    ["Here's what lives above this place:\n", ["ls","-larth", ".."]]
]

# Here we iterate through the list.
for item in command_list:

    # Execute your command using subprocess.Popen
    with subprocess.Popen(item[1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as proc:

        # Assign its output to 'out'
        out = proc.stdout.read()

        # And print the message you have associated with the command,
        # along with 'out', and any output from stdout andstderr
        print(item[0], out)
        print()
```

Hope this helps. Happy New Year!